# How to access developer mode on industrial android device?

Tags: android, adb

What I have is a cash register machine with a preinstalled custom launcher and Android 7.0

How to access the developer options and connect via adb?

I tried switching to recovery mode, but it didn't help me - it shows "no command"

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is forum for Android development, you should post to [android.stackexchange.com](https://android.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Get in touch with the device manufacturer?

Comment: Thanks, for advices, I just had no idea, how to start solving the problem

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to follow this manual on how to [activate developer](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/dev-options) options. If you can't find those settings then it is removed from the manufacturer. Could be that they have an backdoor through some serial port, but again, this is manufacturer knowledge.

Comment: Yes, I tried that manual, but there is no "build number" button in settings, so you are right, the settings are possibly removed by manufacturer